# Vtiger add search fields in accounts module

Tags: vtiger

I want to customize the account's list view by adding a new search field.
I edit $field_list and $field_list_names but nothing appears in the UI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a new Filter (http://prntscr.com/emjxaz) and set a default(http://prntscr.com/emjxng) with your list of Field in ListView.

There is also an another way to add new field in Default Filter but you must have knowledge about vtiger structure. You can apply this query with your required field details

```
INSERT INTO `vtiger_cvcolumnlist` (`cvid`, `columnindex`, `columnname`) VALUES ('1', '8', 'vtiger_leaddetails:firstname:firstname:Leads_First_Name:V');
```

I have given Query to add First Name in My List view Field list. You have to replace field name with yours.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can I ask another question: In which tables are saved 'To Do'? I am trying to track down the data flow when adding a new 'To Do'.

Comment: you can get that under vtiger_activity table

Comment: How 'To Do' are distinguished from 'Events'? Thank you for your quick answer.

Comment: They are having different fields and some custom logics. Events are like your activity and reminders in day to day life. And To do's are your task in your day to day life. For both vtiger will remind you. In Events you can invite other people as well.